# Is there a way to derive the chart from an axis in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number of generic VBA macros for manipulating Excel charts (e.g. overlaying one chart on top of the other; rescaling the axes; or adding a custom curve such as "y = x^2 - 1" to a chart by typing the formula in a text box). These macros are subs which don't take any argument, I store them in a .xlam add-in and run them from linked buttons on the Excel ribbon. In order to run the macro on a specific chart, you select the chart and then click the button on the ribbon.

In order for the macros to know which chart they are operating on, I have a function like this:

```
Function chart_from_selection() As Chart

  If TypeName(Selection) = "ChartArea" Or TypeName(Selection) = "PlotArea" Then
    Set chart_from_selection = Selection.Parent
  ElseIf TypeName(Selection) = "Series" Then
    Set chart_from_selection = Selection.Parent.Parent
  Else
    MsgBox ("Select a chart!")
  End If

End Function
```

So the first couple of lines in each macro are

```
Dim cht As Chart
Set cht = chart_from_selection()
```

and the macro identifies the chart whether you have selected its chart area, plot area or one of its series.

I would also like it to work if you have selected one of the chart axes, but the problem is that the parent of the axis object is the worksheet not the chart. Does anyone know how to derive the chart object itself from one of its axes? The only way I can think of is by recording the position of the axis and then comparing it against the positions of all the charts in the worksheet until you find and overlap, but that seems quite convoluted and I'm wondering if I'm overlooking a simpler way ...

Comment: Having an axis selected, `? typename(selection.parent)` gives `Chart` for me. Also you should really use `TypeOf ... Is ...` instead of the string type name comparisons.

Comment: Hmm no I definitely get `? TypeName(Selection.Parent)` gives `Worksheet`. Should have said, I'm using Excel V14 (2010), VBA 7.0. `TypeOf Selection.Parent is Chart` also evaluates to false. What's the rationale for preferring TypeOf over TypeName?

Comment: The rationale: Type-safe, fully qualified, more tick-efficient check that won't give a false positive if someone comes up with an ActiveX object whose unqualified type name happens to be PlotArea too. Re the worksheet problem: Indeed returns Worksheet in Office 2010, which to me looks like a huge compatibility problem and/or a bug. I now wonder what happens in v2013.

Comment: `If TypeOf Selection Is Gridlines Or TypeOf Selection Is Axis Then Set parentChart = ActiveChart`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I think I may have a solution for you:

```
Sub Find_Chart()

Dim C As ChartObject
Dim sAx As Axis
Dim Axs As Object

'Check if selection is axis
If TypeOf Selection Is Axis Then
    Set sAx = Selection
End If

'Loop through charts
For Each C In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    'Loop through axes
    For Each Axs In C.Chart.Axes
        If Axs.AxisTitle.Caption = sAx.AxisTitle.Caption Then
            Debug.Print C.Name
        End If
    Next Axs
Next C

End Sub
```

For the above code to work, your chart axes must all have titles... If your charts don't have titles (and you'd prefer to keep it that way), you could add titles and change the font to white to keep your charts looking clean. Each title must also be unique. Devise an ID system to ensure all titles are unique (e.g. Chart1AxV, Chart1AxH, Chart2AxV, etc.). If you have preexisting titles and some are duplicated, you can add a unique ID to the end of the title and format the ID part of the label to be white.

The above code loops through each chart in your sheet and checks each axis in the chart. If the axis title is the same as the selected axis's title, the name of the chart is printed to the immediate window.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: `If TypeOf Selection Is Gridlines Or TypeOf Selection Is Axis Then Set parentChart = ActiveChart`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input @GSerg. So I went the long route of figuring out the chart by comparing against the axis position. In case anyone is interested, here is the code. It can be run either by providing an axis object as an explicit argument, or else with no argument but an axis selected in the spreadsheet.

Unfortunately the axis coordinates are relative to the chart not the worksheet, so the method is not fail safe. Basically it goes through the charts one by one and for each chart checks whether any of its axes have the exact same coordinates as the given axis. It could fail if two axes on different charts happened to have identical relative positions to their respective charts.

```
Function chart_from_axis(Optional ax As Axis) As Chart
' Returns the chart from one of its axes. Necessary because the axis parent is the
' worksheet not the chart

  If ax Is Nothing Then
    If TypeOf Selection Is Axis Then
      Set ax = Selection
    Else
      Exit Function
    End If
  End If

  Dim co As ChartObject
  For Each co In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    If axis_belongs_to_chart(ax, co.Chart) = True Then
      Set chart_from_axis = co.Chart
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next co

End Function

Function axis_belongs_to_chart(ax As Axis, cht As Chart) As Boolean

  If axes_coincide(ax, cht.Axes(xlCategory)) = True Or _
     axes_coincide(ax, cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)) = True Then
    axis_belongs_to_chart = True
  ElseIf cht.Axes.Count = 3 Then
    If axes_coincide(ax, cht.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary)) = True Then
      axis_belongs_to_chart = True
    End If
  End If

End Function

Function axes_coincide(ax1 As Axis, ax2 As Axis) As Boolean

  If ax1.Top = ax2.Top And ax1.Left = ax2.Left And ax1.Height = ax2.Height _
    And ax1.Width = ax2.Width Then axes_coincide = True

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I revised the above solution to change the Axis Title to a unique value, find the chart based on the unique value, and then change it back...it returns the chart

```
Function GetChartFromAxis(Axis As Axis) As Chart
Static UniqueIndex As Long
Dim OriginalTitle As String, UniqueName As String
Dim oSheet As Worksheet
Dim oChartObj As ChartObject
Dim oAxis As Axis

    ' Force a Unique Axis Title
    If UniqueIndex > 100000 Then UniqueIndex = 0
    UniqueIndex = UniqueIndex + 1
    UniqueName = "GetChartFromAxis" & UniqueIndex
    If Axis.HasTitle Then
        OriginalTitle = Axis.AxisTitle.Caption
    Else
        Axis.HasTitle = True
    End If
    Axis.AxisTitle.Caption = UniqueName

    ' Find the Axis base on the Unique Title
    Set oSheet = Axis.Parent
    For Each oChartObj In oSheet.ChartObjects
        'Loop through axes
        For Each oAxis In oChartObj.Chart.Axes
            If oAxis.HasTitle Then
                If oAxis.AxisTitle.Caption = UniqueName Then
                    Debug.Print oChartObj.Name
                    Set GetChartFromAxis = oChartObj.Chart
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If Not GetChartFromAxis Is Nothing Then Exit For
    Next

    ' Reset the Axis Title
    If OriginalTitle <> vbNullString Then
        Axis.AxisTitle.Caption = OriginalTitle
    Else
        Axis.HasTitle = False
    End If
End Function
```