# Gridline object... How to retrieve the reference to the worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, gridlines

how to retrieve the reference to the chart and to the worksheet where the chart of the gridline object is, starting from the object itself?

For example, if I have a Range object, the object.Parent is the reference to the Worksheet.
How to do it if the starting object is the gridline object of a chart embedded into a worksheet?

Thanks in advance to everyone can help to put me in the right direction

Comment: One step from this question  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045305/is-there-a-way-to-derive-the-chart-from-an-axis-in-excel-vba

Comment: I have already seen that post... I have the problem that I use Axis titles and some of them are based on a formula. How to add a prefix "Chart1AxV-" to the current formula in axis title caption and format it to be white and leave the rest of the formula in Automatic color?

Comment: Yust to be clear... the Xaxis title caption is a link to a cell, in that cell there is a formula whose result is the string I want. I can add every prefix I want in that formula but it should then be formatted to be white and the rest leaved to be automatic... I don't know how to do it

Comment: You can't do mixed formatting on a chart like you can't do it in a cell with a formula.  You have to update the chart axis label using a macro instead of a link.

Answer (score 0):

I start using the answer of the post [stackoverflow.com/questions/24045305](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045305/is-there-a-way-to-derive-the-chart-from-an-axis-in-excel-vba). Then I added a For.. Next cycle through the worksheets collection (I don't have only one sheet and it is not always the same Chart of interest).

Furthermore, because of the AxisTitle caption is currently meaningful for me and its value is based on a cell formula result (it can't be prefixed and formatted to be white and the rest leaved to be automatic), I solved the problem adding a textbox whose value is now the cell formula result and the AxisTitle caption contains now only the unique identifier formatted to be white.